# How can you use PointLight or another light to shine 360 degrees around when the light is positioned in the center of an object?

Tags: three.js

I know that PointLight won't work if you position it in the center of an object, but that's exaclty what I need to do unless there's another way. Basically I have a solar system (original i know) with the sun being at 0,0,0. I need to point light at 0,0,0 so as the object rotate and orbit the sun, the light will shine accordingly. From what I understand, directional light is a one way thing where point light is 360 degrees. Any ideas how i can accomplish what I'm trying to do...here's my code: http://www.benmarshall.me/projects/playground/072012/solar-system.html (it may be broke at times since im currently working in it, but ill try not to keep it broke for very long so ppl can see it)

Comment: How about having translucent spheres over each planet with a texture that is half dark and half light, you could orient each sphere so that the lighter part always faces the sun? Just a suggestion, its looking nice good work.

Comment: I like that suggestion... but would love an easier way if there is one. It may be easy to be, but I just started using webGL last week so I've got a bit of a learning curve. I 've got like 5 or 6 other questions up right now about some other stuff